# scripting library and function templating

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

## Context

I'm currently working on my own library for loading custom script inside c++ applications.
Here's some sample code for explaining what it's doing:

1. script part:

test.ctv

```
script
{
  object player = access("player");
  player.posX = 1 + 2;
  access("map").load("map.txt");
}
```

2. C++ part:

test.cpp

```
class Player : public Loadable{
private:
 friend class cTVScript::scriptExecutor;
 primaryLoadable<int> posX;
 stringLoadable name;
public:
 Player() : Loadable(&posX, "posX", &name, "name");
}

class Map : public Loadable{
private:
 friend class cTVScript::scriptExecutor;
 std::string mapName;

public:
 void load(std::string map) {
  mapName = map;
 }
 Map() : Loadable(&load, "load") {}
}

int main() {
 Player *p = new Player();
 Map *m = new Map();
 cTVScript::LoadScript("test.ctv");
 cTVScript::AddObject(p, "player");
 cTVScript::AddObject(m, "map");
 std::cout << player.posX.get() << std::endl; // for example purpose we just assume that posX are public
 std::cout << player.mapName.get() << std::endl; // same for mapName
}
```

## Problem

Variable accessing and using by the `cTVScript::scriptExecutor` is quite simple,
but my main problem is elsewhere:

- How, in c++, can I save and call method/functions with differents prototype?
- Some trick with the compiler could make it easier? (like knowing the type and numbers of arguments?)

## Current Work-Around

Make the user define a sub-fonction like `AccessibleLoad`:

```
class Map{
 [...]
 public:
 void load(std::string map) {
  mapName = map;
 }
 static void AccessibleLoad(cTVScript::CallingPack& pack) {
  /* arguments */
  std::string map;
  pack.loadArguments(map); // here the user ask for each arguments

  /*calling object */
  Map* _this;
  pack.loadCallingObject(_this); // and here he ask for the calling object

  _this->load(map);
 }
 Map() : Loadable(&AccessibleLoad, "load") {}
}
```

## So!

Is there a trick or some way i could make it more easy for using functions/methodes in my library? (like constructing these functions with the compiler? (don't think so but better to ask))

## Edit

There's news! I got my own answer, and i'll post it (but it's a bit long)
(by the way, english is not my native language so if i made an error, said me so, i'll edit)

Comment: Consider to use existing solutions, like Tcl in C++: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/Tcl ...

Comment: @PiodrNycz  that's effectively a nice library that i used before... but i kinda want to create mine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Detail On the Context

For more Understanding (and if one want to re-use my solution), I'l detail the context of what i'm doing:

- There's a top level (accessible only by the `cTVScript::Executor`)
- And a low level (Visible (or almost) by the user)

top Level (or Non-typed part)

```
/*                                                                                                                                     
* Non-Typed Part                                                                                                                       
*/
class Loadable{
public:
  virtual std::string getAsString() { return ""; }
};

struct parametersPack{
public:
  Loadable* returnValue;
  std::vector<Loadable*> arguments;
};
```

Low Level (or typed-part)

```
class StringLoadable : public Loadable{
private:
  std::string value;
public:
  StringLoadable(std::string _s) : value(_s) {}
  virtual std::string getAsString() { return value; }
  virtual std::string get() { return value; }
  virtual std::string& getRef() { return value; }
};

template<typename type>
class primaryLoadable : public Loadable{
private:
  type value;
public:
  primaryLoadable(type _v) : value(_v) {}
  virtual std::string getAsString() { return std::to_string(value); }
  type get() {return value;}
  type& getRef() {return value;}
};
```

## Save Function with non-matching prototype

A Parent Function Class (for stocking them):

```
class functionLoadable : public Loadable{
public:
  virtual void call(parametersPack& pack) = 0;
};
```

And Sub-Function (one with void return and other with typed-Return)

```
/*                                                                                                                                     
* Static Loadable Function                                                                                                             
*/
template <typename Return, typename... Arguments>
class StaticLoadableFunction : public functionLoadable{
private:
  Return (*fn)(Arguments...);
public:
  Return calling(Arguments... args) {
    Return value = fn(args...);
    return (value);
  }
  virtual void call(parametersPack& pack) {
    Unpacker::applyFunc(pack.arguments, fn);
  }
  StaticLoadableFunction(Return (*_fn)(Arguments...)) : fn(_fn){}
};

template <typename... Arguments>
class StaticLoadableFunction<void, Arguments...> : public functionLoadable{
private:
  void (*fn)(Arguments...);
public:
  void calling(Arguments... args) {
    fn(args...);
  }
  virtual void call(parametersPack& pack) {
    Unpacker::applyFunc(pack.arguments, fn);
  }
  StaticLoadableFunction(void (*_fn)(Arguments...)) : fn(_fn){}
};
```

## Now the work of the unpacker

First I need to unpack my `arguments` from my `std::vector`

```
  /*                                                                                                                                   
  * Unpacking all arguments                                                                                                            
  */
  template<unsigned int N>
  struct helper;

  template<unsigned int N>
  struct helper{
    template <typename ReturnType, typename... Arguments, typename ...final>
    static ReturnType applyFunc(std::vector<Loadable*> parameters, ReturnType (*fn)(Arguments...), final&&... args) {
      return (helper<N - 1>::applyFunc
              (parameters, fn,
               convertLoadableTo< typename parametersType<N - 1, Arguments...>::type >
               ::transform(parameters[N-1]),
               args...));
    }
  };

  template<>
  struct helper<0>{
    template <typename ReturnType, typename ...Arguments, typename ...final>
    static ReturnType applyFunc(std::vector<Loadable*> parameters, ReturnType (*fn)(Arguments...), final&&... args) {
      return (fn( args... ));
    }
  };

  template <typename ReturnType, typename ...Arguments>
  ReturnType applyFunc(std::vector<Loadable*> args, ReturnType (*fn)(Arguments...)) {
    return (helper<sizeof...(Arguments)>::applyFunc(args, fn));
  }
```

I know want to know wich type are in each recursion:

```
  /*                                                                                                                                   
  * Getting Parameters type N in variadic Templates                                                                                    
  */
  template <int N, typename... T>
  struct parametersType;

  template <typename T0, typename... T>
  struct parametersType<0, T0, T...> {
    typedef T0 type;
  };
  template <int N, typename T0, typename... T>
  struct parametersType<N, T0, T...> {
    typedef typename parametersType<N-1, T...>::type type;
  };
```

And then downcast my `Loadable*` object into primaryLoadable<> or StringLoadable

```
  /*                                                                                                                                   
  * Treat For Each Type                                                                                                                
  */
  template <typename arg>
  struct convertLoadableTo;

  template <typename arg>
  struct convertLoadableTo{ // int, double...etc                                                                                       
    static arg transform(Loadable* l) {
      primaryLoadable<arg>* _l =
        dynamic_cast< primaryLoadable<arg>* >(l);
      if (!_l)
        throw;
      return (_l->get());
    }
  };

  template <typename arg>
  struct convertLoadableTo<arg&>{ // int&, double&...etc                                                                               
    static arg& transform(Loadable* l) {
      primaryLoadable<arg>* _l =
        dynamic_cast< primaryLoadable<arg>* >(l);
      if (!_l)
        throw;
      return (_l->getRef());
    }
  };

  template <>
  struct convertLoadableTo<std::string>{ // int&, double&...etc                                                                        
    static std::string transform(Loadable* l) {
      StringLoadable* _l =
        dynamic_cast< StringLoadable* >(l);
      if (!_l)
        throw;
      return (_l->get());
    }
  };

  template <>
  struct convertLoadableTo<std::string&>{ // int&, double&...etc                                                                       
    static std::string& transform(Loadable* l) {
      StringLoadable* _l =
        dynamic_cast< StringLoadable* >(l);
      if (!_l)
        throw;
      return (_l->getRef());
    }
  };
```

## That's the end!

If you wanna know more detail please mp me!

Answer (score 1):

doing the C++ -> your script call. This is c++11 by the way

You will need some form of packer that can take a type and add it in.

```
class SomeClassYouCanCallAScriptFunction {
    // the order of these templates matter or else
    // the one bellow will not be able to find the one higher

    template<class T, class... Args>
    callFunction(string name){
         // run your code to call your scripted function
         // arguments has the arguments array
    }

    template<class T, class... Args>
    callFunction(string name, T var){
        // last one
        // either this
        arguments.pack<T>(var);
        // or this
        arguments.pack(to_string(var));
        // or the like
        // now do the next one
        callFunction(name);
    }



    template<class T, class... Args>
    callFunction(string name, T var, Args... args){
        // either this
        arguments.pack<T>(var);
        // or this
        arguments.pack(to_string(var));
        // or the like
        // now do the next one
        callFunction(name, args...);
    }







}


someClass.callFunction("scriptFunc", "ya", 42, someVectMaybe);
```

The otherway around the best you can do is provide a `arguments` variable and let the user get a argument passed in like `arguments.get<T>(index)`

Comment: your answer is quite usefull, but i already found another way to do it, i will experience it a bit and post it here later! (But I keep you int touch!)

Comment: If you wanna know why i don't accepted your answer is the way you do it, argument deduction will be done at compilation time, but what i want is a deduction at run-time!